# How to get image url in css inside a public folder in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a css located inside the public/ folder in rails. I want to locate the images inside the app/assets/images/ folder for a background in the css. The code below doesn't seem to work:

```
background: url("bg-noise.png");
```

This is normally used for css inside the app/assets/stylesheets/ folder. Can't make it work inside the public folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two alternatives. If you can rename the file and use the asset pipeline with SCSS, then rename the style to `.css.scss` and replace

```
background: url("bg-noise.png");
```

with the `image-url` SCSS helper.

```
background: image-url("bg-noise.png");
```

It will automatically resolve the path.

Another solution is to rename the file to `.css.erb` and you'll be able to use ERB code inside the file.

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'bg-noise.png' %>)
```

The last solution is to hard-code the path.

```
background: url("/assets/bg-noise.png");
```

I encourage you to use the first option.

Answer (score 2):

You better use this to locate your images

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'bg-noise.PNG' %>)
```

and if you have an images folder use:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path '/images/bg-noise.PNG' %>)
```

Comment: would this work under public/mailer.css? I mean can you place the erb code inside css?

Comment: look at this documentation. you should fix that yourself http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: you have to use the app/assets folder in new rails apps. rails does not search in public/assets.

Comment: This won't work unless you append the .erb extension to the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

if u inspect that element and expend the tab background: url(); and look for image background-image: url('localhost:3000/assets/bg-noise.png');

so in order to avoid that, use

```
{
background: url('../bg-noise.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('/assets/bg-noise.png');
```